# Weird script error with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I run this on jsfiddle it works as expected, randomly increasing or decreasing the number inside the div by 5 every 1 second, but when I run it as inline JS on an html file it waits 1 second, then just changes by 5 every half a second or less

http://jsfiddle.net/cT7a9/219/

I just cannot see what I'm doing wrong here, very irksome

```css
setInterval(function() {
  random=(Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1));
  var plusOrMinus=Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1: 1;
  random=random * plusOrMinus;
  currentnumber=document.getElementById('number');
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=parseInt(currentnumber.innerHTML) + random;
}

, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="number">123</span>
```

Comment: You have different delays in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cT7a9/219/) and the code that you posted here and I believe you are using the delay of 1000ms, that's the reason you are getting delay of 1s. See if this solves the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `inline JS on an html file`? Do you mean in an inline handler, or in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Script tag is what I eamn

Answer (score 0):

You are giving 1000 ms in parameter. It should not wait 5 seconds. Anyway, I think you can try putting the `<script> ... </script>` at the end of your `<body>` tag.
Or you can put your function in an "on ready" function of jquery like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your Interval Code Here
});
</script>
```

FYI : Do not forget to include jquery as "ready" function is in jquery library.

Comment: Same problem unfortunately even if I do both of these things

Comment: @Bigguy I saw your other doubt in JBDouble05's answer. You can Keep your Random numbers between a range like : `random = Math.floor(100 + Math.random()*(106-100+1));` Replace 100 with your lowest number & 106 with highest.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is declaring your function and then *referencing* it, not calling it, in the `setInterval()`. Here's how I would do what you are proposing:

```js
function funcName() {
  random = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
  var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
  random = random * plusOrMinus;
  currentnumber = document.getElementById('number');
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = parseInt(currentnumber.innerHTML) + random;
}

setInterval(funcName, 5000);
```

```html
<span id="number">123</span>
```

Just ask if you need any clarification.

Comment: I thought an easier way of doing it

setInterval(function() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $('#number').text(number);
},
1000); // every 1 second

How would I choose a range of numbers to randomise it between, say 100 and 106?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your JS code into function and add it in `onload` body like that :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="myFunc();">
    <script>
        function myFunc(){
            setInterval(function(){
            random = (Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1));
            var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
            random = random * plusOrMinus; 
            currentnumber = document.getElementById('number');
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML =  parseInt(currentnumber.innerHTML) + random;
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
    <div id="number">123</div>
</body>
```

I tried it, it's working correctly